# Android sdk how can i insert a rate this app alert?

Tags: android, sdk

I maked an App and now I want that when an user start my app, he will see an alert that say "Hello, Rate this App" and I want that the users can select "yes" or "no".

How can i make all of this?

Thanks :)

Comment: why would you ask your users to rate your app before they've even used it? If it were me I would give it the lowest rating possible and un-install ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Don't prompt the alert at the beginning of the app. You should show alert when the user is leaving the application and not every time. After 4-5 day interval show the alert. Here is the complete tutorial how to show this kind of alert.
[Prompt engaged users to rate your app](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater) .Hope it will help you.